# Close modal by clicking BROWSER back button

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

Currently i just have this:

```

```
<div data-slideid="1" class="slide">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center modal-intro">
                <div class="container"><img src="assets/images/work/logo1.png" width="100" height="100" alt="Logo" class="img-circle"/><span>ABOUT</span>
                  <h3>Some text</h3>
                  <p>some more text </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

```

Basically when a button is clicked it just slides modal in on the same URL. I need # or something to be added to the URL when modal is opened so people can click back button in the browser to go back.

I have X close button and everything but a lot of people use back button to go back and i would like to have it added.

Is there a simple way of acomplishing this?

Comment: jQuery history plugin

Comment: alright i will check it out homi ty a lot pc out

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate

Comment: [html5History api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ensureHash(newHash) {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        return window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.lastIndexOf(window.location.hash)) + newHash;
    }
    return window.location.hash + newHash
}
```

Use the `function` above to set the URL you need and do this when you call a button

```
window.location.href = ensureHash("#foo=bar");
```

Comment: OK Lajos, i have this

<a href="#work-gallery" data-slideID="0" class="open-gallery-link">

And if i do $(".open-gallery-link").on('click', function(){
  window.location.href = ensureHash("#foo=bar");
});

It doesn't work, what am i doing wrong? I also have the function above copy/pasted.

Comment: @TheGarrus how is it not working in your case? Is there an error message in the console? Or there is an undesired behavior? One thing is for certain: you have a href in your anchor tag pointing to a hash. If you do not define any Javascript for it, then clicking on it will jump the page to the tag which has the value after the hash as the id. If you write some Javascript affecting the click, then you will need a return false; at its end to prevent the default browser events.

Comment: If i press back button, all it does is remove the hash. It doesn't really go back to the previous page.

Comment: I got it to work, its cool. I also had e.preventDefault, that might be the cause of it.

Answer (score 1):

Was searching for pure JS trick to make it work and came up with this solution:

```
events() {
  // listen for close icon click
  this.closeIcon.addEventListener("click", () => this.closeModal());

  // listen for keyboard
  document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => this.keyboardClose(e));

  // when the user clicks back in the browser, close modal window
  // basically works on any state change, on forward too, but it doesn't really matters in my case
  window.onpopstate = function () {
    document.querySelector(".modal").classList.remove("modal--visible");
  };
}

//adds ?modal to the link and creates new state in the browser history
openModal(e) {
  this.modal.classList.add("modal--visible");
  history.pushState({ modal: 1 }, "modal", "?modal");
}

//if modal is closed in any way, move back in history (without reloading the page)
closeModal() {
  this.modal.classList.remove("modal--visible");
  history.back();
}

//if esc or backspace is pressed, close the modal
keyboardClose(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27 || e.keyCode == 8) {
    this.closeModal();
}

//if modal is closed in any way, move back in history (without reloading the page)
window.onpopstate = function () {
  document.querySelector(".modal").classList.remove("modal--visible");
};
```